# How to write a python program for the following?

Tags: python

I have 50 csv files named with a unique id in a folder. In each of the csv files, there are names and their corresponding scores (out of 100). Now I have to filter the csv sheet based on the score>50 and get the corresponding names in text files named with the unique id just as the csv file from which it was taken and put them in a new folder. The following is the code I have written but the output is not as expected.

```
import glob, os
os.chdir("path of the folder")
for file in glob.glob("*.csv"):
    with open(file,'r') as fin:
        next(fin) #skip the header row
        for row in csv.reader(fin, delimiter=' '):
            for col in csv.reader(row, delimiter=','):
                if int(col[1])>50
                    for i, line in enumerate(fin):
                        f=open("Path to the new folder/output_%i.txt" %i, 'w')
                        f.write(col[0])
                        f.close()
```

The above code generated one file for each score which lies greater than 50 which i dont want. So I request you to correct the above code to help me get the required output. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you give some input lines with the expected output?

Comment: What do you want to do, then? Your code asks if a value in column 2 is more than 50, if so then iterates through the entire file, this time not using the csv reader and for each line   outputs the contents in column 0 to a new file bearing that line's index.

Comment: Remove the second iteration. If value is more than 50, output the data to a new file, but don't index by the line number, but generate a unique id.